# Kohana can't find controller from other module when uploaded to the server

Tags: php, kohana, autoloader, kohana-3.3

I have an application that is **working fine locally**. However, when it was uploaded to my **(shared) server**, it wasn't able to find one of the controllers (that was exteded to). I suspect that it happened because this controller is in another module (which **I made sure it was activated** in the bootstrap file). The projects isn't in the server's root file and it has been recently upgraded from 3.0 to Kohana 3.3, but I don't think this is the problem.

**The structure is something like this:**

`Controller_Home extends Controller_GradeHorariaFrontEnd` <=They are both in the same module

`Controller_GradeHorariaFrontEnd extends Controller_Base_FrontEnd` <= They are in different modules

And the error I get is:
[image: Print screen of the error caused when I tried to access the application in the server]

Comment: i think there is something wrong with making available the files from the module containing Controller_Base_FrontEnd in the current controller. I think that because there weren't problems when Controller_Home extended Controller_GradeHorariaFrontEnd (same module), but the problem was raised when Controller_GradeHorariaFrontEnd extended Controller_Base_FrontEnd (different modules). Additionally, when I checked in the "included files" section in the profiler, the file that  contains the class Controller_Base_FrontEnd wasn't there (included).

Comment: it's weird that it works locally, but it doesn't work in the server. Couldn't it be because locally I use Windows and my shared server uses Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the filename was Frontend.php, while it should have been FrontEnd.php, as it is in the name of the class (Controller_Base_FrontEnd). It worked in windows (localhost) because it is case insensitive, but didn't in linux (in my server) because it is completely case sensitive.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as correct. I have exactly the same issue.